# Oracle: Change and read a :NEW variable in the same trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

Have the following situation: An insert trigger is being fired when a new row gets added to Table A.
The trigger needs now to modify a value in this new row (in Table A) and overwrite what has initially been inserted.
At the same time the trigger also has to read a different value (diffrent collumn) from Table A from the same row to insert something in Table B.

Can this work in a single trigger?

If I use an "after trigger", I can read the value to insert in table B, but I cannot modify table A because of a "table mutation error".

If I use an "before trigger", I can modify the value in A sucessfully, but the value I want to read for Table B is always NULL.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: So now I finally had the code here and I tried the method with two triggers, but I realized that it cannot work either ><

The code I have so far (sorry for the german words. "benutzerkonto" means "useraccount", btw):

```
create or replace trigger TRG_TEST_LOGIN_BENUTZERKTO
  before insert on benutzerkonto
  referencing new as new old as old
  for each row
begin
  /* with 1/3 probability, the user is set to be logged in */
  if (dbms_random.value(0,3)) <= 1 then
    :NEW.LOGGED_IN := 1;
    dbms_output.put_line('The TEST_LOGIN_BENUTZERKTO Trigger fired');
  end if;
end TRG_TEST_LOGIN_BENUTZERKTO;
/


create or replace trigger TRG_TEST_CREATE_SESSION
  after update on benutzerkonto
  referencing new as new old as old
  for each row
declare
  geraet smallint;
begin

  dbms_output.put_line('The TRG_TEST_CREATE_SESSION Trigger fired');

  /* Choses a random device (gerät) */
  geraet := round(dbms_random.value(1001,1103),0);

  /* A new session with the new "benutzerkonto" shall be added. */
  INSERT INTO SESSION_LOGGING (BENUTZERNAME, GERAET_ID, ZEITSTEMPEL_LOGIN, ZEITSTEMPEL_LOGOUT) VALUES (:NEW.BENUTZERNAME, geraet, sysdate, NULL);

end TRG_TEST_CREATE_SESSION;
/
```

What this is supposed to do, is randomly set newly added useraccounts to logged in (for testing purposes). This actually works, the first trigger fires correctly.

Now I want when this trigger has changed the LOGGED_IN part to "1", that the second trigger (the update trigger) fires too, to create the associated row in the SESSION_LOGGING table.

This trigger never fires though since saying :new.LOGGED_IN = 1; obviously doesn't count as an update on the table.
I cannot use an UPDATE statement instead though, since else Oracle says that I'm "mutating" the table >_>

So how could this be solved?

Comment: I think you can do this.  Edit your question and show the trigger code (or at least a version that extracts the relevant logic).

Comment: So where does the value you want to insert into B come from?  You say it is "from the same row" but if this is true how can it be NULL in the BEFORE trigger state.

Comment: It is from the row which has been added by the INSERT command which triggered the trigger.
Guess that does make sense, doesn't it? The "before trigger" fires before the values of the new row are inserted, or not?
Sadly I don't have the code here right now >< (it is a group work) but OI'll hopefully be able to post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of writing compound trigger, use before/after update trigger on that differential column so that when we insert into table a it automatically calls  before insert trigger .Then you said the updating the specific column then use before or after update on table_A(column_name) then insert those value in the table B.

Comment: We didn't have compound triggers yet in class and it's probably better not to spontanously add them...

Have updated the post with code now!

Comment: when i had tried the above trigger i am getting the following error. **[Error] Execution (43: 8): ORA-04091: table EMP_ASK is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "TR_EMP_ASK_BRU", line 2 ORA-06512: at TR_EMP_ASK_BRU", line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TR_EMP_ASK_BRU'** is the same error you are getting?

Comment: Uhm, no.. the triggers doesn't cause any errors. Sure you don't have any foreign stuff in your table? Because there is no table called "EMP_ASK" in my code, nor is a trigger "TR_EMP_ASK_BRU". Or did you rename my triggers?

Comment: actually i had executed in my table name **emp_ask** and trigger name is **tr_emp_ask_bru** is the trigger name.

Comment: Which of the triggers did you rename? There are two triggers up there. But like I said, for me they work flawlessly, except that the second trigger never fires.
Anyways, how would you fix the issue you got?

Comment: i think there is a problem in the first trigger because we cannot insert and update the values in a single table inside a trigger. i think mutation error is caused in first trigger not the second one

Comment: Huh, well, like I said, the first trigger works fine in my case, the second one is just never being executed.
The first alters the current value of LOGGED_IN to 1. That I tested.

Comment: check whether the LOGGED_IN has the value 1 after execution?

Comment: It does have and we finally just solved the issue!
It worked by making both triggers, INSERT triggers instead of an update and an insert trigger. The second trigger is an AFTER trigger.

THanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If your Oracle is newer than 11.1 you can create a compount trigger, see here: [Compound Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CIHEFGFD).
There you have `BEFORE (FOR EACH ROW)` and `AFTER (FOR EACH ROW)` in one block.

Comment: We didn't have compound triggers yet in class and it's probably better not to spontanously add them...

Have updated the post with code now!